# How to backup the software installed via Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, snap, flatpak

So I used to hate Ubuntu Software Center (SC) in 14.04 and 16.04 because it was very buggy and nothing really worked. Now with 18.04 everything works perfectly and installing flatpak plugin for it opens the door to a lot more software and newer. So, snaps, flatpaks, and the other ones, SC is a great and super easy tool to find pretty much anything. I moved away from installing via the terminal as I used to, but I lack something now: I used to also backup my sources.list so when I would install Ubuntu again I could easily reinstall all of my software again. Not anymore now since I install them via SC.

My question is: how do I backup all of my installed software that is done via SC? Would love to see something as simple as "reinstall all your apps" option. SC should have such an option.

Thanks!